# Web-scraping. How make it faster ?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter, html

I have to extract some attributes(in my example there is only one: a text description of apps) from webpages. The problem is the time !
Using the following code, indeed, to go on an page, extract one part of HTML and save it, takes about 1.2-1.8 sec per page. A lot of time. Is there a way to make it faster ? I have a lot of pages, x could be also 200000.
I'm using jupiter.

```
    Description=[]
    for x in range(len(M)):
        response = http.request('GET',M[x] )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data,"lxml")
        t=str(soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"section__description"}))
        Description.append(t)
```

Thank you

Comment: You could look into multiprocessing.

Comment: Is `M` a list of urls?

Comment: Matt Cremeens, yes, it is

Comment: Use scrapy for faster scraping!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [inspecting the page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference) a bit. If page relies on the Rest API, you could scrape contents that you need by directly getting them from the API. This is much more efficient way than getting the contents from HTML.
To consume it you should check out [Requests library for Python](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I would try carving this up into multiple processes per my comment. So you can put your code into a function and use multiprocessing like this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def web_scrape(url):
    response = http.request('GET',url )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data,"lxml")
    t=str(soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"section__description"}))
    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # M is your list of urls
    M=["https:// ... , ... , ... ]
    p = Pool(5) # 5 or how many processes you think is appropriate (start with how many cores you have, maybe)
    description=p.map(web_scrape, M))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    description=list(description) # if you need it to be a list
```

What is happening is that your list of urls is getting distributed to multiple processes that run your scrape function. The results all then get consolidated in the end and wind up in `description`. This should be much faster than if you processed each url one at a time like you are doing currently.

For more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Matt Creemeens, I'm trying your solution right now and I'm looking at the documentation you gave me. I've never used multiprocessing before. Thanks so much

Comment: Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Code is working, thanks. I can't see differences in term of time. Probably because I have only 2 cores

Comment: How many urls do you have to process? You could also consider running this on a server, like pythonanywhere, so you wouldn't have it eating up your own resources and perhaps make use of more CPUs.

Comment: About 200000. Thanks, I will  consider using resource of servers